# Display Post in wordpress through PHP Code

Tags: wordpress

i have prepare a scroller and need to show in footer of the `wordpress` page. it has provided me an `ID`, not able to show it in footer file, its display as it `code` which i have putted it in post page.Using the below Plugin `http://www.gopiplus.com/work/2011/05/08/wordpress-plugin-image-horizontal-reel-scroll-slideshow/#.UKX1ie-0Ndg`

I have applied the code in post as `[ihrss-gallery type="gallery1" w="600" h="170" speed="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" gap="5" random="YES"]`

Any help ?

I am using below code --

```
<?php
$post_id = 11893;
$queried_post = get_post($post_id);
$title = $queried_post->post_title;
echo $queried_post->post_content;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use the Loop first before using the post_content like that

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
               <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>    
               <!-- do stuff ... -->
               <?php endwhile; ?>
     <?php endif; ?>
```

Follow this guide
http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

Answer (score 0):

For more details of get_post click this link - 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post

```
$my_id = 297;
$post_id_7 = get_post($my_id);
$title_7 = $post_id_7->post_title;
echo $title_7;
$content_7 = $post_id_7->post_content;
echo $content_7;
```